# Grails 3.x and Jenkins: Save BUILD_NUMBER and date when deploying

Tags: grails, jenkins, groovy, deployment, build

I have a Grails 3.1 application which is build and deployed with Jenkins. Now I am searching for a way to save the [BUILD_NUMBER](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) and several other variables in my Grails app to display them inside a GSP later.

I found [this tutorial/code snippet](http://akeffalas.github.io/blog/2014/04/jenkins-build-info-grails-war.html) but it seems to work with Grails 2.x apps only? Also I considered the new location of the "src/main/scripts" folder in Grails 3.x apps for the "_Events.groovy" file.

Can anyone help me to get the build number and date dynamically into my grails app to show them e.g. in the footer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grails 2.x build system is based on [Gant](https://gant.github.io/). When a given gant script executes, it can trigger certain events that you can hook into and provide custom behavior. One such event is `eventCreateWarStart`, and that's what the `_Events.groovy` script does in the link you provided.

Grails 3.x uses Gradle as the build system. As such, any previously existing Gant scripts must be converted to use Gradle instead.

#### Manifest

To do something similar to the link you provided, i.e., append the `Implementation-Build-Number` attribute to the manifest file, you would need to add this to your Grails 3 project's `build.gradle` file:

```
task addBuildNumber() {
    def unknownValue = 'UNKNOWN'
    def buildNumberEnvironment = 'BUILD_NUMBER'
    def buildNumberProperty = 'build.number'
    def buildNumber = System.getenv(buildNumberEnvironment)

    if (!buildNumber) {
        buildNumber = System.getProperty(buildNumberProperty, unknownValue)
    }

    war {
        manifest { attributes "Implementation-Build-Number": buildNumber }
    }
}

tasks.war.dependsOn(addBuildNumber)
```

We're [defining a custom task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) called `addBuildNumber` and configuring the existing `war` task to depend on `addBuildNumber` when it is invoked. The `addBuildNumber` task attempts to retrieve the build number and append it to the war's manifest.

#### Views

Getting the build number and other variables inside of views is a bit different. To get this working, you need to add all of the variables you're interested in to the `application.yml` file. Let's add our build number with a placeholder to the metadata that's already in there:

```
info:
  app:
    name: '@info.app.name@'
    version: '@info.app.version@'
    grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
    build-number: '@info.app.build-number@'
```

Then you'll need to render that in your footer gsp page with the [`<g:meta>` tag](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/meta.html) where the `name` is the configuration property from `application.yml`:

```
<footer>
    <span class="build-number"><g:meta name="grails.info.app.build-number"/></span>
</footer>
```

And finally, you need to replace the `@info.app.build-number@` placeholder in `application.yml` as part of the build process, so we'll configure the existing `processResources` task by adding the following to `build.gradle`:

```
processResources {
    def unknownValue = 'UNKNOWN'
    def buildNumberEnvironment = 'BUILD_NUMBER'
    def buildNumberProperty = 'build.number'
    def buildNumber = System.getenv(buildNumberEnvironment)

    if (!buildNumber) {
        buildNumber = System.getProperty(buildNumberProperty, unknownValue)
    }

    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['info.app.build-number': buildNumber])
}
```

From the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#N115CC),

> When you use the ReplaceTokens class with the “filter” operation, the result is a template engine that replaces tokens of the form “@tokenName@” (the Apache Ant-style token) with a set of given values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed information! It helped me a lot! But there was one little mistake. It has to be '<g:meta name="info.app.build-number"/>' inside the GSP. Notice: "grails." has to be removed from the name parameter.
Thank you so much.